# Sum $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{\left(\left(2n-1\right)^2\right)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

How to find sum $\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{\left(2n-1\right)^2}$ from sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$?

The first sum I found by integration of Fourier series of function $f(x)=x$ for $-\pi\leq x\leq \pi$, but I still don't know how to find the other sum.

Any hint or help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look here ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant

Comment: @ Donald Splutterwit I found by WolframAlpha that answer is Catalan constant, but I'm interested to know how to calculate it by using Fourier series. Is it even possible to do by using Fourier series of function $x\to x^2$ for $-\pi\leq x\leq \pi$?

Comment: Might be an idea to add these to your question ... & anything else you already know or require in an answer.

Comment: @Donald Splutterwit Could you help me further on?

Comment: Sure ... That's why I gave you the Catalan constant ref ... It would appear that this series cannot be expressed in terms of any simpler constants. Have a look at Aprey's constant ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)^2} = G =0.915 \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
The Catalan constant.

Of course you know Euler's solution to the Basel problem
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{ \pi^2}{6}
\end{eqnarray*}
and from this it is easy to calculate the sum of the reciprocals of squares of ... (positive ) even numbers , odd numbers ... and if you subtract these you will get the alternating result that you state in your question
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2} = \frac{ \pi^2}{12}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So the next obvious question is the one you are asking ... alternating odd numbers ... and it would seem that this cannot be simplified & it is called the Catalan constant.

Note also that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{ \pi^4}{90}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So one might reasonably suppose that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3} = r \pi^3
\end{eqnarray*}
where $r$ is a rational value. But it turns out not to be the case ... & this is called Aprey's constant ... check it out
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant

Even more wierd ... the alternating sum of reciprocals of (positive) odd numbers cubed can be simplified 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)^3} = \frac{ \pi^3}{32}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

The way to understand both is to consider $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n^2}$ and
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-z)^n}{n^2}$.